# SQL Inner Join query doesn't return all records, but instead the first one ever made

Tags: php, sql

```
SELECT user.name, comments.cdata, comments.likes FROM comments
WHERE pid = $postNum 
INNER JOIN user ON comments.uid = user.uid 
ORDER BY cdate
```

Quick Notes:

1. I am a beginner, please don't be rude to me, I am trying to learn more
2. Yes, I have tried LEFT JOIN, but that just returns an SQL sintax error
3. My database is like this:
   2 tables, 1 one is comments, comments has comments.cdata, comments.likes and comments.uid, the user one has the name of the user.

What I have been trying to accomplish is getting the name of the user with the comment data, instead of UID and comment data.

I also can not use 2 queries, due to me getting all the records and then displaying them on page via PHP for each.

Comment: Consider creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Comment: I'd expect a syntax error. The WHERE clause should be after the joining, just before the ORDER BY.

Comment: the problem is that the name of the second commenter doesn't show, but the error dissapears

Comment: it works nvm lol

Answer (score 0):

Your query is syntactically incorrect.  `JOIN` is an operator in the `FROM` clause.  `WHERE` is a clause that follows the `FROM` clause.

In addition, I think the `cdata` and `cdate` should be the same thing, although I don't know what.

I also recommend using table aliases.  So:

```
SELECT u.name, c.cdata, c.likes
FROM comments c JOIN
     user u
     ON c.uid = u.uid 
WHERE c.pid = $postNum 
ORDER BY c.cdata
```